# Prove that $x\in \mathbb{R}>0 \rightarrow \exists y\in \mathbb{R}>1$ s.t. $ xy>1$.

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I am going through my practice sheet before finals in my proofs class, and I would like critique, please.

My understanding of the If-Then and the "hidden implications" is that each real number $x>0$ has at least one $y>1$ such that  $xy>1$. If this is the case, then it is true, and here is my formal proof:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $y \in \mathbb{R} s.t. y=\dfrac {1} {x}+1$. Since $x>0, \dfrac {1} {x}>0$, and $y=\dfrac{1} {x}+1>1,$ and $xy = x(\dfrac {1} {x} + 1) = 1 + x >1$.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Your choice of $y$ is a good one, but you have proved that $y>1$.  You need instead to prove that $xy>1$.

Comment: Also, xy = 1+x, not 1+1/x. But both exceed 1.

Comment: @vadim123 I did fix that. Thank you.

Comment: @martycohen, I figure I'll eventually get it right! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that proof is correct. Well done.